# Why does pgAdmin3 set OIDS=FALSE and owner to postgres by default?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Why does pgAdmin3 automatically set the table owner to `postgres` when its created and set `OIDS=FALSE`? I am new to PostgreSQL and want to know the rational behind this default behavior.

```
-- Table: staging.mytable

-- DROP TABLE staging.mytable;

...

WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

ALTER TABLE staging.mytable
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1 Why oids=false?**

OIDS=FALSE/TURE,  the default setting depends upon the **default_with_oids** configuration parameter，The parameter is off by default。in PostgreSQL 8.0 and earlier, it was on by default.

**2 Why ownered by postgres?**

Please check the role you use log in  when using  pgAdmin3 ， if you log in as postgres role ,then  the owner of  new created table will be the postgres role.